# Css header page with html in bulma

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

Hello I have a problem.

Why my css doesn't work on my head page in html?

Someone can help me the link of my code if you to see the result on run: [https://jsfiddle.net/02kf1msd/`](https://jsfiddle.net/02kf1msd/%60).

I use bulma for the style.

I want to have the logo and the menu in the same header line: logo on left and menu nav on right.

HTML Code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Oumar Pathe SOW Portfolio </title>
  <!--css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/main.css">
  <!--css-->
  <!--font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--font-->
</head>
<!--head-->

<!--body-->

<body>
  <!--head-->
  <div class="block">

    <head class="header">
      <a href="#" class="header-logo"> Oumar Pathé SOW Portfolio</a>
      <nav class="header-menu">
        <a href="#">Accueil</a>
        <a href="#">Apropos</a>
        <a href="#">Réalisations et Expériances</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </head>

  </div>
  <!--head-->
```

CSS Code:

```
.header header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba( 0 , 0 , 0, 0);
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.header .header-logo {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.header .header-menu{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.header .header-menu a {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header .header-menu a:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}
```

Why my access doesn't apply on this code?

Comment: In your css file you have .header header, that doesn't exist. Try with only .header

Answer (score -1):

sometimes Bulma style overrides your CSS codes so you will need to use !important after some of your CSS attributes.

second use navbar-end and navbar-start classes to make the logo on left and menu nav on right,
https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/